# Does snmp have a standard MIB for crc errors or is it HW dependent?

Tags: ethernet, snmp

I am looking for a common MIB that supports checking of crc errors, does this depend on hardware vendor and a custom MIB like CISCO?

Comment: Which CRC errors? Different protocols, at different layers, may, or may not, do error checking with CRCs.  For instance, IPv4 has a Header Checksum, but IPv6 doe not. Ethernet has a Frame Check Sequence, but other layer-2 protocols do not.

Comment: General CRC I guess? When I run show interfaces Ethernet 0 from a switch per say, I can find a line that says (e.g. 3 CRC). Ahh sorry, this should have the Ethernet tag added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exists in the EtherLike-MIB (dot3statsFCSErrors), but just because a MIB exists doesn't mean a vendor supports it.  Most vendors have a custom MIB that supports CRC/FCS errors and it shouldn't be hard to build a list based on that.